# c++ pipe: does it wait on write

Tags: unix, pipe

I use pipes to communicate between processes. When I write to a pipe, and I read it slower than I write, will write() block until the atomic write to the pipe is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least if the number of bytes being written is smaller than the number guaranteed to be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

`write()` is not required to write all the data passed - it can write less and you have to check how much has actually been written.

Answer (score 1):

A POSIX conform system should block.

From the write(2) manpage:

"POSIX  requires  that  a read(2) which can be proved to occur after a write() has returned returns the new data.  Note that not all file systems
       are POSIX conforming"